# Charging a subview during the time my main subview is not loaded

Tags: iphone

I a loading a tableview wich takes data from the web (with a XML parser). But using the 3G it takes some times until I get all off my datas. So I would like to load a subview (with only a label "loading... " on it) during the time my data is not loaded.
How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should download the data *asynchronously*. (For example, if you use NSURLConnection, use the `+connectionWithRequest:delegate:` and handle the data in a delegate object.)

Before the data is loaded, put the subview in.

In the data-receiver delegate, take the subview out in the "done" method (e.g. `-connectionDidFinishLoading:`.)